# Why doesn’t my HTML5 form work in Android emulators?

Tags: android, html

```
<form action="test2.html" method="POST" autocomplete="on" id="myForm" >
<table>

    <tr>
        <td>
            Name: 
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="text1" pattern="[A-z]{3}"/><br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Email:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="email" id="mail" autofocus="autofocus"/><br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            URL:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="url" id="url"/><br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Number:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" id="num"  required="required" onSubmit="click()"/><br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Date:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="date" id="dat"/><br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Range:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="range" id="range" min="1" max="10"/><br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Search:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search W3Schools"  /><br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Color:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="color"/><br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            DataList:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="url" list="url_list" name="link" />
            <datalist id="url_list">
            <option label="W3Schools" value="http://www.w3schools.com" />
            <option label="Google" value="http://www.google.com" />
            <option label="Microsoft" value="http://www.microsoft.com" />
            </datalist><br/>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            Points: 
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="points" min="0" max="10" step="3" /><br/>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            Output:
        </td>
        <td>
            <output id="result" onforminput="45"></output><br/>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            Image
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="image" src="client.png" width="40" height="40" /><br/>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

This is the form that runs fine in "chrome" but whn i try and run it on android emulator, none of the validations seem to work. Any suggestions on what can be done?
Also, when i enter value in a textbox, it automatically takes in the value of prev textbox and appends it, Any suggestions on what can be done abt that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think Andriod supports HTML5 form validation. May find this link useful: [Form Validation Support](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#validation)

Maybe something like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) might be good, but maybe JavaScript is your best bet.